# Is it possible to set access priority to files in windows

Tags: windows, filesystems

i am working on a system that has 2 parts. the parts are as follow:
1- a producer application that generate and append files in space A, and i cannot modify it ( i must not make noise for this part).

2- a transformer application that copies the files from space A(near the part1) to Space B.

. If part 2 starts to copy a file from A to B and during the copying of the file, part1 wants to append the same file, the part1 will stopped, because the file is under control of part2.

I want to if the part1 wants to append the file, control of the file granted to part 1, and it's not important to what happens for part2.

IS it possible to do that in windows??

Answer (score 0):

If you are working within one computer system (not via network), then in general the correct way would be to monitor the writes, made by part 1, as they happen, and copy the written data on-the-fly. This is achieved using a file system filter driver, which intercepts write operations and captures the data being written.